# Am I returning a generic type in a good way

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to return a Generic type, the issue i'm having is that when i'm in debug, the application fails when i try to inspect the returned value.

So if i have

```
public class BaseRepository : IBaseRepository
{
    public BaseRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    protected IDbContext Context { get; private set; }

    public TEntity Get<TEntity>(Guid id) where TEntity : class
    {
        IDbSet<TEntity> entitySet = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();
        return entitySet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

and i try to do

```
var entity = studentRepository.Get<Student>(...)
```

When i put a breakpoint in that like i'm not able to inspect the value of entity, and my application then fails. The function and the call is in 2 different assemblies, if that might have something to do with the issue.

I got this message:

> Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'entity' as it is not
>   available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been
>   optimized away.

And then w3wp.exe crashes

So i guess i'm not using that generic type as I should

So is it possible to have such `Get` in a Repository without having to specify the Generic type in `BaseRepository` like `BaseRepository<TEntity>`

Comment: Any error message you want to share? If not, define 'it fails'.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i have updated the question with the message

Comment: @Lloyd Yes of course its when i try to inspect `entity`AFTER the line is executed

Comment: How do you debug this?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I attach to the w3wp.exe process in debug. If I put my break point in `IDbSet<TEntity> entitySet = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();` and then do F10 to the caller. Then i'm able to see the value of `entity`. Or if i call `studentRepository.Get<Student>(...)` in the immediate window i'm able to see the value.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's why i guess this has something to do with C# optimization and the fact the caller and the Repository are in 2 different assemblies

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311303/cannot-obtain-value-of-local-or-argument-as-it-is-not-available-at-this-instruct

Comment: And this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/01/27/how-to-disable-optimizations-during-debugging.aspx

Comment: Try to set build mode to `Debug` instead of `Release`.

Comment: I'm already in `Debug` and I reproduce the issue if I run the website via F5 (Start Debugging)

Comment: I've installed the Framework 4.5.2 and it fixed the issue. cf https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/819552/visual-studio-debugger-throws-accessviolationexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed the **Framework 4.5.2** and it fixed the issue. cf

[reference](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/819552/visual-studio-debugger-throws-accessviolationexception)