# Cannot watch contents of variables when debuggin ASP.NET 5 IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging, dnx

When I debug an ASP.NET 5 web application it hits my breakpoints, but I cannot watch the contents of variables created locally.

Example code from startup.cs using empty project as template:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    var dummy = DateTime.Now;

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World! " + dummy);
    });
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on "app.Run(...." it hits the breakpoint but I cannot see the content of variable dummy. If I add *dummy* to Watch it says **"error CS0103: The name 'dummy' does not exist in the current context"**.
Although I can see the contents of DateTime.Now, which gives me the exact Date and Time every time I hover it.
The same happens when I put a breakpoint in an MVC controller and watch variables overthere.

I was following a Pluralsight course and I also have this with the project I created while following that course, as well with the example files that come with the course.

During debug VS2015 is attached to the dnx.exe process
In the video I see the VS2015 is attached to the IISExpress.exe process. But that course is from nov. 2015 perhaps something changed in the meanwhile.

Reboot of machine didn't help.

This is my first question over here, if more info is needed please let me know, and I'll do my best to provide.

Comment: Apologies if this is a silly question, but are you running your application in Debug mode or Release mode? In Release mode, optimizations are done that make it impossible to show the value of some variables.

Comment: @Pooven Yes it's in Debug mode, platform is Any CPU.

I saw that I didn't described the issue correct yesterday. I've added the error I get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer. Sometimes a night of rest does miracles.

I did a Google search on 'error CS0103: The name  does not exist in the current context debug'. Without the word 'debug' you get a lot of results that don't help.
I've found the following site: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1038150/visual-studio-2015-debugger-doesnt-recognize-a-variable

The answer is: Menu > Debug > Options, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode". Checked that option and it worked for me.
Also for the project I was working on.

Comment: Took me like the whole day to find this.

Comment: Even though it does work, it is still a workaround, i think there might be an underlying issue.

Comment: Could be, but it worked, so I'm happy ;-) 
I think it's one of those things that you get for free when working with bleeding edge/pre-release technologies.

Comment: In addition to this setting, I had to change some project level settings: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311303/cannot-obtain-value-of-local-or-argument-as-it-is-not-available-at-this-instruct

Answer (score 0):

Been searching the whole day for this. Enabling Use Managed Compatibility Mode did the trick. It allowed me to quickwatch the contents of my class, so that I could see that one of my get methods was referencing itself instead of the class attribute. Silly typo that broke my application.
So I agree that this is a workaround and doesn't solve the underlying issue, but it helps finding it!

Comment: But it isn't a solution.