# Unable to solve "Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer"

Tags: .net, debugging

I have an MVC app, which calls into some middleware buried within microsoft's own assemblies. Microsoft's code is throwing a index out of range exception and I need to debug it.

The problem occurs within `ValueStringBuilder` in the `AppendFormatHelper` method.

There is a big ol' call stack full of juicy info that would probably help me debug it.

However I've enabled every single debug option I can find, disabled optimisations, etc from a variety of other stackoverflow posts, and I still get this error when the code breaks on the throw exception line (using Exception Settings > Break When Thrown):

> Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.

Previously I was getting "Variable value is not available because the module is optimized. Click the drop down for options." but I found some additional debug settings.

The only thing I saw in the other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311303/cannot-obtain-value-of-local-or-argument-as-it-is-not-available-at-this-instruct) was that it says "Also, set the "Debug Info" dropdown to "Full" in the Advanced Options (Under Build tab)." however I don't have this option and can't find it anywhere.

I've attempted to follow everything in that SO link, suppress JIT, disable optimisation, check it's running under debug, I even found debug launch profiles UI > IIS > enabled debugging.

Is it possible to see variable values in external code loaded this way via the Microsoft symbols server?

I am using VS 2022 Professional, project is an MVC application .NET 6 (with a class library or two). I've enabled all the debugging stuff for each project, if that's important.

Comment: You can't enable Debug build on pre-built Framework assemblies. You can only do that for the assemblies you build. The existing ones are already compiled as Release build

Comment: Surely the microsoft symbols server would serve up them built as Debug...

Comment: Firstly, no it won't because it doesn't have them. Secondly even if it did, you don't have the debug build of ther assembly so it won't match.

Comment: Seems like a rather pointless feature then if you can't get the values out, there is no way for me to debug why this code is breaking because it's entirely within microsoft's own middleware and I don't know what value has been supplied to the method that is causing the problem.

Comment: I would think it highly unlikely that it's actually their issue and much more likely an issue in how you are using it. Please provide a [mcve] showing what you are doing, and the full exception with stack trace.

Comment: It's not possible for me to produce that given the complexity of the project, the issue appears to be that the middleware generates a redirect but doesn't supply a parameter for the callback url to the string.format which then fails because it expects two parameters to be supplied. Since I can't debug it or create a reproducible example of such a complex website I will close this question.

Comment: Perhaps you can debug it higher up the stack, in the middleware?

Comment: The stack is like 35 nested calls within the middleware, unfortunately, the stack trace is several pages long. Oddly it does tell me the value of the string it's trying to format, which is something like `statusCode={0}&backLink={1}`, and higher up in the callStack it invokes it with `ParamsArray { statusCode }` without supplying the link. To me, that looks like a bug. Maybe I can flag it on their github.